# How to split values in a single column and assign to matching columns in pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with a column contain multiple values. I need to split the values and assigned them to separate but matching columns. Example Fruits column contain different fruits. I need to splits these fruits and assign apple to apple column, banana to banana column ..etc.

```
    fruits
0   apple/mango
1   grapes
2   orange/apple
3   grapes/orange/apple/banana
4   banana/grapes/apple
```

I created  data frame but when I split values in a row ,these values are added to multiple rows  instead of single row. There should be 5 rows in new data frame but I'm getting 12 rows

```
columns_name =['apple','banana','grapes','orange','mango']
fruits =df['fruits'].to_list()
columnlists_list =[]
for column in columns_name:
  column_list = column
  column_list =[]
  columnlists_list.append(column_list)
  for fruit in fruits:
    one_fruit = fruit.split('/')
    for i in range(0,len(one_fruit)):
      if column == one_fruit[i]:
        column_list.append('1')
      else:
        column_list.append('0')
#data frame 
fruits_df = pd.DataFrame(columnlists_list)
fruits_df =fruits_df.transpose()
fruits_df.columns =[columns_name]
```

This the result I got.

```
    apple   banana  grapes  orange  mango
0   1       0       0       0        0
1   0       0       0       0        1
2   0       0       1       0        0
3   0       0       0       1        0
4   1       0       0       0        0
5   0       0       1       0        0
6   0       0       0       1        0
```

Please advise how to correct the error. Thank you

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: It should be  1st row : Apple  and Mango 1 rest 0, 2nd row:  only Grapes is one, 3rd row :both Orange and  apple 1 rest 0..like that. New dataframe should contain only similar number of rows to original dataframe. that is 5 rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `get_dummies` method in the str accessor (.str) from [pandas working with text data](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/text.html#working-with-text-data):

```
df['fruits'].str.get_dummies(sep='/')
```

Output:

```
   apple  banana  grapes  mango  orange
0      1       0       0      1       0
1      0       0       1      0       0
2      1       0       0      0       1
3      1       1       1      0       1
4      1       1       1      0       0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can start by unnesting your data using `explode()`.This requires a column of list type values which you can achieve with `str.split('/')`.

Then you can use `get_dummies()` which will use all the unique values of your 'fruits' column, and chain `groupby` to get one row per index:

```
# Unnest your dataframe
expl_df =  df.fruits.str.split('/').explode().reset_index()
>>> print(expl_df)

    index  fruits
0       0   apple
1       0   mango
2       1  grapes
3       2  orange
4       2   apple
5       3  grapes
6       3  orange
7       3   apple
8       3  banana
9       4  banana
10      4  grapes
11      4   apple

# Convert your fruits to columns
pd.get_dummies(expl_df, columns=['fruits'],prefix='', prefix_sep='').groupby(['index'], as_index=False).sum().drop('index',axis=1)

   apple  banana  grapes  mango  orange
0      1       0       0      1       0
1      0       0       1      0       0
2      1       0       0      0       1
3      1       1       1      0       1
4      1       1       1      0       0
```

Comment: Yes its worked. Thank oyu

Answer (score 0):

Here is my attempt:

```
df['fruits']=df['fruits'].str.split("/")
columns_name =['apple','banana','grapes','orange','mango']

membership_info = []
for elem in df['fruits']:
    membership = []
    for fruit in columns_name:
        membership.append(1) if fruit in elem else membership.append(0)
    membership_info.append(membership)

result_df = pd.DataFrame(membership_info, columns= columns_name)
print(result_df)
```

Output:

```
   apple  banana  grapes  orange  mango
0      1       0       0       0      1
1      0       0       1       0      0
2      1       0       0       1      0
3      1       1       1       1      0
4      1       1       1       0      0
```